# Asynchronous javascript issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, asynchronous

I'm trying to make a function `details()` that looks up the details of certain events (`getdetails`) based on the available events. In the example below, details are asked for the events with IDs ZRGZZ, RGHER and GRFDZ. These details should be placed inside one array (credits to [Theodore's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34498313/955823)). The result should be that when I call `details()`, the resulting array is stored so I can use it later on.

The problem is that I don't know how I can return this final array. `console.log(JSON.stringify(res));` is executed before the construction of the array is completed. I know this probably has something to do with asynchronous js, but I just can't wrap my head around it...

```
function details()
{
    var res = {
    "Result": "success",
    "Key": "12345",
    "Data": [{
        "ID": "ZRGZZ",
        "lastChangedDate": "2015-12-03 11:14:27"
    }, {
        "ID": "RGHER",
        "lastChangedDate": "2015-12-03 15:17:47"
    }, {
        "ID": "GRFDZ",
        "lastChangedDate": "2015-12-03 05:25:11"
    }]
};

    var i = 0;
    var tmp;
    res.Data.map(function(val,i){

        getdetails(val.ID).then(function(data){
            tmp = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(tmp);
            Object.keys(tmp.Data[0]).map(function(v,j){
                val[v] = tmp.Data[0][v];
                console.log(JSON.stringify(res)); //(*)the last res gives me the result I'm looking for
            });

        }, function(error){ //error callback
            console.log(error)
        });


    });
console.log(JSON.stringify(res)); //this is executed before (*)
}
```

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/ks3vxomu/

Comment: I see angular in your tags, if you are able to use angular it is very easy to make asynchronous calls with $http.get which gives you a promise(the object you need)

Comment: @RayonDabre that seems to change the structure of my data

Comment: @luk492 I'm using this inside an Ionic app, so indeed there's angular, but I'm very new to angular... Could you maybe point me in the right direction how this could work?

Comment: @binoculars Try looking at this link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you already use promise - see `then` in your code and if it's angular then `then` itself return deferred promise so you can do:

```
res.Data.map(function (val, i) {
    getdetails(val.ID).then(function (data) {
        tmp = JSON.parse(data);
        Object.keys(tmp.Data[0]).map(function (v, j) {
            val[v] = tmp.Data[0][v];
        });
    }, function (error) { //error callback
        console.log(error)
    }).then(function () {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
    })
});
```

EDIT: inject service `$q` into your controller or service

```
promises = [];
res.Data.map(function (val) {
    promises.push(getdetails(val.ID).then(function (data) {
        tmp = JSON.parse(data);
        Object.keys(tmp.Data[0]).map(function (v, j) {
            val[v] = tmp.Data[0][v];
        });
    }, function (error) { //error callback
        console.log(error)
    }));
});
$q.all(promises).then(function () {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
});
```

now when all the `getdetails` are resolved you can console.log or do whatever you want with the data

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This seems to work! The only thing that isn't ideal is that it `console.log(JSON.stringify(res));` is executed x times (x being the number of IDs it has to search).

Comment: I'll update my answer with a bit more complicated solution to address this problem

Comment: I tried your updated answer, but now `res` only holds the details for the first event.

Comment: I've changed inside of your code when I was checking it, try now, i've put the original logic inside

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot (!), couldn't have done this myself.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library, in particular the [`async.each`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) or `async.eachSeries` function. (You could use `async.map`, but in your case you are actually not mapping, but modifying the underlying array items directly.)

In particular, your code would look like this:

```
async.each(res.Data, function(val,callback){
    getdetails(val.ID).then(function(data){
        tmp = JSON.parse(data);
        Object.keys(tmp.Data[0]).map(function(v,j){
            val[v] = tmp.Data[0][v];
        });
        callback(null); // Asynchronous code has finished without error
    }, function(error){ //error callback
        callback(error); // Asynchronous code has finished with error
    });
}, function(error) {
    // All asynchronous calls have finished
    if(error)
        console.log("Error", error);
    else
        console.log("Success", res);
});
```

`async.each` will run many iterations at the same time, while `async.eachSeries` will run only one iteration at the same time.