# Construct new array based on lastChangedDate

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a `refreshdata()` function which executes a call to get IDs of certain events:

```
function refreshdata()
{
    $http({
        url: “…/GetIDs”,
        method: "POST",
        data: jsonData,
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 7000,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            responseNew=data.d;
            meetings = JSON.parse(responseNew);
            console.log("Got meetings");
            meetingsanddetails(meetings);

        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("Unable to refresh data.”);
        });
}
```

`meetings` is something like:

```
{
   "Result":"success",
   "Key":"12345",
   "Data":[
     {"ID":"GFDCV34","lastChangedDate":"2015-12-03 11:14:27"},
     {"ID":"IDJHE23","lastChangedDate":"2015-12-03 15:17:47"},
     {"ID":"KDJBD34","lastChangedDate":"2015-12-03 05:25:11"}
   ]
}
```

Next, I do `meetingsanddetails(meetings)`:

```
res = meetings;
var i = 0;
var tmp = [];
promises = [];
res.Data.map(function (val) {
    promises.push(getdetails2(val.ID).then(function (data) {
        tmp = JSON.parse(data);
        Object.keys(tmp.Data[0]).map(function (v, j) {
            val[v] = tmp.Data[0][v];
        });
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }));
});
$q.all(promises).then(function () {
    $timeout(function () {$ionicLoading.hide()}, 500);
    $window.localStorage['data'] = JSON.stringify(res);
});
```

`res` is now something like:

```
{
  "Result": "success",
  "Key": "12345",
  "Data":[
    {
     "ID": "GFDCV34",
     "name": "Name of event 1",
     "date": "date of event 1",
     "location": "location of event 1",
     "lastChangedDate": "2015-12-03 11:14:27"
    },
    {
      "ID": "IDJHE23",
      "name": "Name of event 2",
      "date": "date of event 2",
      "location": "location of event 2",
      "lastChangedDate": "2015-12-03 15:17:47"
    },
    {
      "ID": "KDJBD34",
      "name": "Name of event 3",
      "date": "date of event 3",
      "location": "location of event 3",
      "lastChangedDate":"2015-12-03 05:25:11"
    }
  ]
}
```

(credit to [maurycy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34508789/955823))

(Info: `getdetails2(id)` returns the details of an event with a given ID).

This works fine, but the `getdetails2` calls take a long time to load. That is way I would like to make it work like this:
If `…/GetIDs` returns IDs that weren’t already in `$window.localStorage['data']`, they should be added with their details.
The IDs that `…/GetIDs` returns that were already in `$window.localStorage['data’]`, should only be updated if the `lastChangedDate` of the new call is more recent.
IDs that are present in `$window.localStorage['data’]`, but not in the new call, should be deleted.

Anyone who can point me in the right direction? I keep messing up this array hocus pocus.

Comment: using `forEach` instead of `map` at `res.Data.map` is more logically correct

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't rely on `localStorage`: in private mode in Safari it [does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555347/html5-localstorage-error-with-safari-quota-exceeded-err-dom-exception-22-an), so you need to have some fallback to prevent errors.

What you want to achieve is a caching thing. You have two possibilities: do it on your own which would take some time and probably will have some bugs (I did it couple of times and it was not fun at all) or use ready solutions, e.g. this advanced [angular-cache](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache). It allows to choose the storage type, can be natively used with `$http` / `$resource` and allows operations with the cache such as deleting cached responses (that's what you would need to do when you get a newer timestamp). It is quite easy to use, just check the docs and examples.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using this code inside an Ionic app (http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/) for Android and iPhone. Would local storage still be a problem then? It's basically the only this I need to store.

Comment: well, I don't really know what ionic uses as browser... Still that would not be an issue if you use angular-cache, they will care about it.